# Complex logarithm inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove that $\ln(-1+i)^2  \neq 2\ln(-1+i) $, my approach has been the following, transform $-1+i$ to polar form so I get $-1+i = \sqrt2 e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}$.

So $\ln(-1+i)^2 = \ln(\sqrt2 e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}})^2 = \ln(2+e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}) = \ln(2) + i(\frac{3\pi}{2})$

If I do the same with $2\ln(-1+i) = 2\ln(\sqrt2 e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}) = 2\ln(\sqrt2) + 2i(\frac{3\pi}{4}) = \ln(2) + i(\frac{3\pi}{2})$

So I fail to see how they differ, if anyone could point out at which step I did an illegal operation I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments:

A complex logarithm does not behave like a real logarithm. Note that $\ln(2e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}) = \ln(2) + i(\frac{3\pi}{2})$ is NOT true. I believe that you are familiar with a "branch of logarithm." In general complex logarithm is a "multivalued function. The equality is true for the "principal value of the logarithm" where the argument of the given complex number is chosen as the principal argument: An argument which lies in $ (-\pi, \pi].$

Comment: Thanks it's perfectly clear now

Comment: Cool. Happy to help.

Comment: any qucik tip on how to see why the equality doesn't hold unless its the principal value? thx

Comment: Real logarithms don't satisfy $\log(a+b)=\log a+\log b$, either.

Comment: I am afraid I know any quick trick. The underlying philosophy is the following:  If we do not impose this restriction, then the Argument function is NOT a well-defined function.

Comment: @BokaPeer Thanks a lot for all the help! I will look more into it